# convert date to 08%2F15%2F2013%2014%3A23 in python

Tags: python, replace

i'm trying to replace the `/`,`spaces` and `colon` in date with %2F, %20 and %3A

if date is `08/15/2013 14:23`  then i should first convert it into `08%2F15%2F2013%2014%3A23`
So what i did was to use `str.replace(old,new)` function in python to replace the characters but, i wanted to know if there is any library or  direct method to convert the date into required format.

Comment: Maybe urllib.urlencode might come in handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.quote("08/15/2013 14:23", safe='')
'08%2F15%2F2013%2014%3A23'
```

is that what you want?  it seems to give the right answer (i'm just a bit worried as it's 3 hours after asking and no-one else has posted it).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [urllib.quote_plus](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html). This will do `+` instead of `%20` as is the norm in URLs. If you need the `%20` you'll probably have to do it yourself.

```
import urllib
urllib.quote_plus("08/15/2013 14:23") # >> 08%2F15%2F2013+14%3A23
```

Comment: it doesn't handle the forward slash.

Comment: Yup, just saw that. Should have tested before posting.

Comment: No problem. You were too excited.